# How to fetch specific rows from a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor defined as follows:

```
temp_var = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.asarray([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]]))
```

I also have an array of indexes of rows to be fetched from tensor:

```
idx = tf.constant([0, 2])
```

Now I want to take a subset of `temp_var` at those indexes i.e. `idx`

I know that to take a single index or a slice, we can do something like

```
temp_var[single_row_index, :]
```

or

```
temp_var[start:end, :]
```

But how to fetch rows indicated by `idx` array?
Something like `temp_var[idx, :]` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) op does exactly what you need: it selects rows from a matrix (or in general (N-1)-dimensional slices from an N-dimensional tensor). Here's how it would work in your case:

```
temp_var = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]))
idx = tf.constant([0, 2])

rows = tf.gather(temp_var, idx)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(rows))  # ==> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```