# Tensorflow: Is there a way to create multiple gather() outputs and stack them parallely in a compute-and-memory-efficient manner?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to essentially create a 3-D tensor from the indexed rows of a 2-D tensor. For example, assuming I have:

```
A = tensor(shape=[200, 256]) # 2-D Tensor.
Aidx = tensor(shape=[1000, 10]) # 2-D Tensor holding row indices of A for each of 1000 batches.
```

I wish to create:

```
B = tensor(shape=[1000, 10, 256]) # 3-D Tensor with each batch being of dims (10, 256) selected from A.
```

Right now, I'm doing this in a memory inefficient manner by doing a `tf.broadcast()` and then using a `tf.gather()`. This is very fast, but also takes up a lot of RAM:

```
A = tf.broadcast_to(A, [1000, A.shape[0], A.shape[1]])
A = tf.gather(A, Aidx, axis=1, batch_dims=1)
```

Is there a more memory efficient way of doing the above operation? Naively, one can make use of a for loop, but that is very compute inefficient for my use case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract 10,000 rows correct? (10 rows 1000 different times)
make this [1000, 10] array into 1 dimensional array [10000] with reshape

See this answer

[How to fetch specific rows from a tensor in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743538/how-to-fetch-specific-rows-from-a-tensor-in-tensorflow)

This will give you output [10000, 256]

Then reshape the output into your final form. [1000, 10, 256]

I haven't tried it.